# Context free grammar for $L$

Tags: automata, regular-language, context-free-grammar

Find context free grammar for

$$ \left\{  w \in \left\{a,b \right\}^* \mid |w|_a = 2k  \text{ and } |w|_b = 2l+1, l \in \mathbb{N_{0}}\right\} $$

Any hint helps!

Comment: Why do you want a context-free grammar for a regular language? What did you try?

Comment: I want to find the regular expression for the language, which seems hard to do from scratch. I drew the DFA for the language and tried to get the regular expression from there, but it seemed too hard. So I wanted to try to get the regular expression from the grammar.

Comment: You cannot in general convert a context-free grammar to a regular expression.

Comment: In this case, the title of your question is misleading: it is a question on regular languages. I am pretty sure it was already asked on this site.

Comment: A [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1665392/regular-expression-for-strings-with-even-number-of-1s-and-number-of-0s-divisib).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to construct a regular expression for the language of all words with an even number of $a$'s and $b$'s (using similar ideas, you can solve your problem). Let us first consider all words without any $aa$ or $bb$. In this case, the regular expression is simply
$$
(abab)^* + (baba)^*.
$$
Now we want to allow $aa$, i.e., to undo the mapping $aa \to \epsilon$. We simply need to convert any "empty space" to $(aa)^*$, obtaining the regular expression
$$
(aa)^*((aa)^*a(aa)^*b(aa)^*a(aa)^*b(aa)^*)^*(aa)^* + (aa)^*((aa)^*b(aa)^*a(aa)^*b(aa)^*a(aa)^*)^*(aa)^*.
$$
(This is certainly not the most economical way...) Undoing the mapping $bb \to \epsilon$ by converting any "empty space" to $(bb)^*$, we obtain the desired regular expression, which is however too verbose to write.

Comment: Your expression does not seem to match the word $bb$.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin What expression? I haven't actually written it down. You have to insert $(bb)^*$ before and after each symbol.

Comment: Ok, I missed that.